# Finding the first transaction of an account

Tags: stake, index

I'm trying to work my way on indexing old stake accounts, I have the following example:
GbT9rPn4523Hzai789QTMh8Mn3455PZEwdCJeJttWdS7, this is a stake account that used to be active but not anymore, it is not shown under getProgramAccounts for its original owner, nor I get any information from getAccountInfo,
I'm trying to figure out a deterministic way to find the first transaction of the account, but getSignaturesForAddress works only in a descending way,

any ideas how to deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

Using the normal Solana RPC, you'll need to iterate through calls to `getSignaturesForAddress` using the `before` parameter, there's no other way unfortunately.

More info at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getsignaturesforaddress