Fastest way to get the first liquidity pool creation transaction for a given token
I currently have a context where I need to get hash of the first liquidity pool creation transaction on raydium, given a token address.
I know that if I page back through the transactions, I will eventually find it. But this can take a long time depending on the amount of transactions that exist with the token.
I thought about trying to pass some instructions to the RPC to filter by the raydium liquidityPool programId, does anyone have any suggestions?

This might be similar to https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/12028/finding-the-first-transaction-of-an-account
