Get First Mint Txn using Python
how can I obtain the first mint transaction of a token without iterating through all transactions?

This is very similar to https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/12028/finding-the-first-transaction-of-an-account -- you can't!

@JonC ok thanks so much for the reply
