Programatically receive first transaction of solana wallet
Does anyone know how to programmatically receive the first transaction of a Solana wallet besides using the normal Solana RPC and interating through calls to getSignaturesForAddress.
This method leads to getting rate limited extremely fast. Please let me know if there are any other methods
Thank you!

Does this help? https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/12028/finding-the-first-transaction-of-an-account
